# Django Accessing the attributes of an M2M field by querying the related table

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a table which looks like this

```
class Person(User):
    """
    This model represents person's personal and
    professional details.
    """
    attribute1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attribute2 = models.TextField()
    attribute3 = models.TextField()
    attribute4 = models.ForeignKey(Receptionist)
    referred_attribute1 = models.ManyToManyField(Hobby)


class Hobby(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Use case:
A **Person** P1 has **Hobbies** h1,h2,h3(defined[as 3 separate entries] in table Hobby).
Now I want to retrieve a Person object with all the attributes and properties that it has including Hobbies. For that I'm executing the following :

```
Person.objects.values("attribute1",
                      "attribute2",
                      "referred_attribute1").get(attribute3="p1's attribute")
```

What I want is :

```
{'attribute1':'p1_attribute1', 
 'attribute2':'p1_attribute2', 
 'referred_attribute':['h1','h2','h3']}
```

and what I get is:

```
[{'attribute1':'p1_attribute1', 
  'attribute2':'p1_attribute2', 
  'referred_attribute':'h1'},
 {'attribute1':'p1_attribute1', 
  'attribute2':'p1_attribute2', 
  'referred_attribute':'h2'}, 
 {'attribute1':'p1_attribute1', 
  'attribute2':'p1_attribute2', 
  'referred_attribute':'h3'}]
```

Is there a way to get my desired result directly from a queryset? As I do not want to manually re-arrange the above result!

Comment: This is not a straight answer, just a suggestion: use a different query for the many to many relationship and then join it.

Comment: "Use a different query"- Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
p1 = Person.objects.get(attribute3="p1's attribute")
```

p1 is the instance of the person, you can then retrieve all your attributes from it. eg:

```
p1_attribute1 = p1.attribute1
p1_hobbies = p1.referred_attribute1.all()
```

Now you can rearrange that data however you like, for example, making a list of the hobbies as follows:

```
hobby_list = p1_hobbies.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

I would rename referred_attribute1 to hobbies for code readability

Comment: I am doing that already. The itch is that I have a hell lot of data and rearranging that wouldn't be the most efficient way. I need a queryset that I can execute to get the desired values in the desired format.
PS: I named it "hobby". Put it here this way for contextual purpose. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in this case:

```
    [{'attribute1': res.attribute1, 'attribute2': res.attribute2,
    'referred_attribute1': [a.name for a in res.referred_attribute1.all()]}
     for res in Person.objects.prefetch_related('referred_attribute1').filter(attribute3="p1's attribute")]
```

Also see [Django's Prefetch-related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)